# Animate lines within circle - matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

I'm trying to animate lines using matplotlib. I can animate a circle and some scatter points but I'm trying to add lines using a changing angle. Using below, I determine the orientation of `X2`, `Y2` at each point in time to determine the direction. I then want to plot to lines that display this direction. They essentially split the circle up into 4 equal segments. I've inserted each frame individually below. I've entered a compass as a reference.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import animation

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (8,8))
ax.set_xlim(-20,20)
ax.set_ylim(-20,20)
ax.grid(False)

df = pd.DataFrame({   
    'Time' : [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3],             
    'id' : ['A','B','C','D','A','B','C','D','A','B','C','D'],                 
    'X1' : [1,8,0,-5,1,1,-6,0,1,8,0,-5],
    'Y1' : [-5,2,-5,2,5,-5,-2,2,-5,2,-5,2],
    'X2' : [0,0,0,0,-1,-1,-1,-1,0,0,0,0],
    'Y2' : [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],    
    'Rotation' : [0,0,0,0,-0.78,-0.78,-0.78,-0.78,1.57,1.57,1.57,1.57],
    'Angle' : [0,0,0,0,-45,-45,-45,-45,90,90,90,90],                    
    })

points_x = np.array(df.groupby(['Time'])['X1'].apply(list))
points_y = np.array(df.groupby(['Time'])['Y1'].apply(list))

# scatter points
points = ax.scatter(points_x[2], points_y[2], c = 'blue', marker = '*')

moving_x = np.array(df.groupby(['Time'])['X2'].apply(list))
moving_y = np.array(df.groupby(['Time'])['Y2'].apply(list))

# scatter moving
moving_point = ax.scatter(moving_x[2], moving_y[2], c = 'black', marker = 'x')

# Array of immediate congestion radius coordinates
radius = df.drop_duplicates(subset = ['Time','X2', 'Y2'])[['X2', 'Y2']].values

# Plot immediate congestion radius
circle = plt.Circle(radius[2], 10, color = 'black', fill = False)

# Add radius to plot
ax.add_patch(circle)

t = df['Angle'][0]
line1, = ax.plot([0, 0],[0,t], color = 'b', linewidth = 1)

def animate(i) :

    circle.center = (radius[i,0], radius[i,1])

    line1.set_data([i, i],[0,t])

    points.set_offsets(np.c_[points_x[0+i], points_y[0+i]])
    moving_point.set_offsets(np.c_[moving_x[0+i], moving_y[0+i]])


ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate,  np.arange(0,2), blit = False)
```

If I split the frames up individually, I'm hoping they display the following:

Frame 1:
[image]

Frame 2:

[image]

Frame 3:

[image]

Edit 2:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to handle datasets beyond the toy dataset in your post, I put everything for creating an animation into the function `animate`. Since I'm not familiar with the dataset you are working with (for example I don't know what `Rotation`  does), the script below is the best I can do.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import animation

df = pd.DataFrame({   
    'Time' : [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3],             
    'id' : ['A','B','C','D','A','B','C','D','A','B','C','D'],                 
    'X1' : [1,8,0,-5,1,1,-6,0,1,8,0,-5],
    'Y1' : [-5,2,-5,2,5,-5,-2,2,-5,2,-5,2],
    'X2' : [0,0,0,0,-1,-1,-1,-1,0,0,0,0],
    'Y2' : [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],    
    'Rotation' : [0,0,0,0,-0.78,-0.78,-0.78,-0.78,1.57,1.57,1.57,1.57],
    'Angle' : [0,0,0,0,-45,-45,-45,-45,90,90,90,90],                    
    })

# the scattered points in the compass
points_x = np.array(df.groupby(['Time'])['X1'].apply(list))
points_y = np.array(df.groupby(['Time'])['Y1'].apply(list))

# the center of the compass
moving_x = np.array(df.groupby(['Time'])['X2'].apply(list))
moving_y = np.array(df.groupby(['Time'])['Y2'].apply(list))

radius = df.drop_duplicates(subset = ['Time','X2', 'Y2'])[['X2', 'Y2']].values
angles = df['Angle'].unique()

rot_mat = lambda theta:np.array([
    [np.cos(np.deg2rad(theta)),-np.sin(np.deg2rad(theta))],
    [np.sin(np.deg2rad(theta)),np.cos(np.deg2rad(theta))]
])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (8,8))

def animate(i) :
    
    ax.clear()
    ax.set_xlim(-20,20)
    ax.set_ylim(-20,20)
        
    points = ax.scatter(points_x[i]+radius[i][0], points_y[i]+radius[i][1], c = 'blue', marker = '*')
    moving_point = ax.scatter(moving_x[i],moving_y[i], c = 'black', marker = 'x')
    
    circle = plt.Circle(radius[i], 10, color = 'black', fill = False)
    ax.add_patch(circle)

    ends_one = np.array([[-7.07106781,7.07106781],[7.07106781,-7.07106781]])
    ends_two = np.array([[-7.07106781,-7.07106781],[7.07106781,7.07106781]])
    ends_one = ends_one @ rot_mat(angles[i]) + radius[i]
    ends_two = ends_two @ rot_mat(angles[i]) + radius[i]
    line1, = ax.plot([], [], ls='--', color='black',lw=1, zorder=10,animated=True)
    line2, = ax.plot([], [], ls='--', color='black',lw=1, zorder=10,animated=True)
    line1.set_data([ends_one[0][0],ends_one[1][0]],[ends_one[0][1],ends_one[1][1]])
    line2.set_data([ends_two[0][0],ends_two[1][0]],[ends_two[0][1],ends_two[1][1]])
    
    tags = ['N','E','S','W']
    tag_pos = np.array([[0,8.5],[8.5,0],[0,-8.5],[-8.5,0]])
    tag_pos = tag_pos @ rot_mat(angles[i])
    for tag,pos in zip(tags,tag_pos):
        ax.annotate(tag,xy=pos+radius[i], xycoords='data',
                    fontsize=10,horizontalalignment='right', verticalalignment='bottom')

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, np.arange(0,3), blit = False)
ani.save('test.gif', writer='pillow', fps=3)
```

As you can see, coordinates can be passed iteratively into the function `animate` to generate frames of a compass. After you run this script, you will get a `gif` file `test.gif`, which can be previewed

[image: test.gif]

---

**Remove text of past frames**

There are two ways you can do this

**1. If you are using a function to create animation**

put `ax.clear()` at the beginning of the function, for example

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation

rot_mat = lambda theta:np.array([
    [np.cos(np.deg2rad(theta)),-np.sin(np.deg2rad(theta))],
    [np.sin(np.deg2rad(theta)),np.cos(np.deg2rad(theta))]
])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (8,8))

centers = np.linspace(1,36,36).reshape(18,2)*0.2
angles = np.linspace(45,90,18)

def animate(i) :
    
    ax.clear()
    ax.set_xlim(-20,20)
    ax.set_ylim(-20,20)
            
    circle = plt.Circle(centers[i], 10, color = 'black', fill = True)
    circle.set_facecolor('violet')
    ax.add_patch(circle)

    tags = ['N','E','S','W']
    tag_pos = np.array([[0,8.5],[8.5,0],[0,-8.5],[-8.5,0]])
    tag_pos = tag_pos @ rot_mat(angles[i])
    for tag,pos in zip(tags,tag_pos):
        ax.annotate(tag,xy=pos+centers[i], xycoords='data',
                    fontsize=10,horizontalalignment='right', verticalalignment='bottom')

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, np.arange(0,18), blit = False)
ani.save('test.gif', writer='pillow', fps=18)
```

This will create a `gif` like this

[image: use a function to create]

**2. If you are not using a function to create animation**

You need to manually remove the text, for example

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation

rot_mat = lambda theta:np.array([
    [np.cos(np.deg2rad(theta)),-np.sin(np.deg2rad(theta))],
    [np.sin(np.deg2rad(theta)),np.cos(np.deg2rad(theta))]
])

centers = np.linspace(1,36,36).reshape(18,2)*0.2
angles = np.linspace(45,90,18)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (8,8))
ax.set_xlim(-20,20)
ax.set_ylim(-20,20)
    
circle = plt.Circle(centers[0], 10, color = 'black', fill = True)
circle.set_facecolor('violet')
ax.add_patch(circle)

annotates = []
tags = ['N','E','S','W']
tag_pos = np.array([[0,8.5],[8.5,0],[0,-8.5],[-8.5,0]])
tag_pos = tag_pos @ rot_mat(angles[0])
for tag,pos in zip(tags,tag_pos):
    ann = ax.annotate(tag,xy=pos+centers[0], xycoords='data',
                      fontsize=10,horizontalalignment='right', verticalalignment='bottom')
    annotates.append(ann)

for i in range(18):
    
    circle.center = centers[i]
    # remove the previous text
    for item in annotates: item.remove()
    annotates = []
    
    tag_pos = tag_pos @ rot_mat(angles[i])
    for tag,pos in zip(tags,tag_pos):
        ann = ax.annotate(tag,xy=pos+centers[i], xycoords='data',
                          fontsize=10,horizontalalignment='right', verticalalignment='bottom')
        annotates.append(ann)

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, np.arange(0,18), blit = False)
ani.save('test.gif', writer='pillow', fps=18)
```

as you can see, with this line of code `for item in annotates: item.remove()`, the text of a previous frame are removed. Therefore, by running this script, you will also get

[image: the new one]

Comment: @jonboy Hi jonboy, is this gif what you are looking for?

Comment: thanks for looking at this. I can see the lines are animating for you. They aren't appearing for me. I'm also hoping to not hard code any coordinates. My actual data frame is quite large and i'm hoping to pass the coordinates in iteratively.

Comment: @jonboy You are welcome, I have updated my answer, where I put everything regarding animation into the function `animate`, so you can pass data iteratively without hard code coordinates. I don't understand what do you mean by the gif aren't appearing for you, since I have uploaded the output gif file to the post. If you cannot preview the gif in the post, you can run the script, it will create a gif file `test.gif`.

Comment: I only had animations within the function because I have separate items to plot. I've rearranged your code to get it working where I only animate the items that change (scatter, circle, lines). However, the text marking the compass points are giving me trouble. I don't wan't to clear the axis for each frame so I'm returning the points for each frame.

Comment: @jonboy I'm glad you have resolved your problem, clear the axis is used because the positions of the objects cannot be updated when using a function to plot. In fact, if I understand correctly, you don't want the text marking to change, inside the function, you can just plot the text marking at the same position for every frame.

Comment: Thanks. I've uploaded a separate gif to display my issue. I need a predetermined axis, while animating sepcfici items. I've removed everything except the circle and text. The circle animates as intended but the text doesn't get removed for past frames.

Comment: Is there anyway at all to keep the animate function and incorporate the text. I'd like the initial animate function because I have numerous other items to plot here. It may have to be another question

Comment: @jonboy please ask another question, this post has already been edited multiple times :)

Answer (score 1):

A new point (x′,y′) is obtained by rotating an existing point (x,y), θ radians around the point (cx, cy) by performing translation, rotation, and a translation operation using the following formula:

```
x′ = (  (x - cx) * cos(θ) + (y - cy) * sin(θ) ) + cx
y′ = ( -(x - cx) * sin(θ) + (y - cy) * cos(θ) ) + cy
```

[image: linescircle]

Programmatically shown here:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math
from matplotlib import animation

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (8,8))
ax.set_xlim(-20,20)
ax.set_ylim(-20,20)
ax.grid(False)

df = pd.DataFrame({   
    'Time' : [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3],             
    'id' : ['A','B','C','D','A','B','C','D','A','B','C','D'],                 
    'X1' : [1,8,0,-5,1,1,-6,0,1,8,0,-5],
    'Y1' : [-5,2,-5,2,5,-5,-2,2,-5,2,-5,2],
    'X2' : [0,0,0,0,-1,-1,-1,-1,0,0,0,0],
    'Y2' : [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],    
    'Rotation' : [0,0,0,0,-0.78,-0.78,-0.78,-0.78,1.57,1.57,1.57,1.57],
    'Angle' : [0,0,0,0,-45,-45,-45,-45,90,90,90,90],                    
    })

points_x = np.array(df.groupby(['Time'])['X1'].apply(list))
points_y = np.array(df.groupby(['Time'])['Y1'].apply(list))

# scatter points
points = ax.scatter(points_x[2], points_y[2], c = 'blue', marker = '*')

moving_x = np.array(df.groupby(['Time'])['X2'].apply(list))
moving_y = np.array(df.groupby(['Time'])['Y2'].apply(list))

# scatter moving
moving_point = ax.scatter(moving_x[2], moving_y[2], c = 'black', marker = 'x')

# Array of immediate congestion radius coordinates
radius = df.drop_duplicates(subset = ['Time','X2', 'Y2'])[['X2', 'Y2']].values

# Plot immediate congestion radius
circle = plt.Circle(radius[2], 10, color = 'black', fill = False)

# Add radius to plot
ax.add_patch(circle)

t = df['Angle'][0]
angles=np.array(df.groupby(['Time'])['Angle'].apply(list))
line1, = ax.plot([],[], color = 'k', linewidth = 1)
line2, = ax.plot([],[], color = 'k', linewidth = 1)

def animate(i) :

    circle.center = (radius[i,0], radius[i,1])

    #set the initial coordinates for line 1
    xs1L1=-10.0/2**0.5
    ys1L1=10.0/2**0.5
    xs2L1=10.0/2**0.5
    ys2L1=-10.0/2**0.5

    #set the initial coordinates for line 2 which is perpendicular to line 1
    xs1L2=-xs1L1
    ys1L2=ys1L1
    xs2L2=-xs1L2
    ys2L2=ys2L1

    # the center of circle 
    cx=radius[i,0]
    cy=radius[i,1]

    # Convert angle from degrees to radians
    theta=math.radians(angles[i][0])

    # rotating line 1 and allowing for translation of line center
    x1L1=(  (xs1L1+radius[i,0] - cx) * math.cos(theta) + (ys1L1+radius[i,1] - cy) * math.sin(theta) ) + cx
    x2L1=(  (xs2L1+radius[i,0] - cx) * math.cos(theta) + (ys2L1+radius[i,1]- cy) * math.sin(theta) ) + cx
    y1L1=( -(xs1L1+radius[i,0] - cx) * math.sin(theta) + (ys1L1+radius[i,1] - cy) * math.cos(theta) ) + cy
    y2L1=( -(xs2L1+radius[i,0] - cx) * math.sin(theta) + (ys2L1+radius[i,1] - cy) * math.cos(theta) ) + cy
    
    line1.set_data([x1L1,x2L1],[y1L1,y2L1])

    # rotating line 2 and allowing for translation of line center
    x1L2=(  (xs1L2+radius[i,0] - cx) * math.cos(theta) + (ys1L2+radius[i,1] - cy) * math.sin(theta) ) + cx
    x2L2=(  (xs2L2+radius[i,0] - cx) * math.cos(theta) + (ys2L2+radius[i,1]- cy) * math.sin(theta) ) + cx
    y1L2=( -(xs1L2+radius[i,0] - cx) * math.sin(theta) + (ys1L2+radius[i,1] - cy) * math.cos(theta) ) + cy
    y2L2=( -(xs2L2+radius[i,0] - cx) * math.sin(theta) + (ys2L2+radius[i,1] - cy) * math.cos(theta) ) + cy
    
    line2.set_data([x1L2,x2L2],[y1L2,y2L2])

    
    points.set_offsets(np.c_[points_x[0+i], points_y[0+i]])
    moving_point.set_offsets(np.c_[moving_x[0+i], moving_y[0+i]])

    return circle, line1, line2, points, moving_point

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate,  np.arange(0,3), blit = True)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks @Sameeresque